# Custom SystemUI

Tags: android, customization

I want to fully customize the SystemUI in Android. I read the code but didn't find Answers to the following Questions:

- Can I get an PackageManager in the System UI to retrieve all installed Applications?
- How does the Android System determinate the Space for the Applications? I expected to found a vertical Layout like this:

  ```
  StatusBar
  ```

  ---

  Apps/Launcher/...

  ---

  ```
   NavBar
  ```

  But I could not find anything like this. Where is the "AppSpace" Defined.
- Where is set that the NavBar is at the Bottom of the Screen and the StatusBar at the Top?

I want to Modify the TabletSystemBar but used the Phone Layout as a Reference of better examples

Answer (score 0):

> Can I get an PackageManager in the System UI to retrieve all installed
>   Applications?

You can get all applications by `PackageManager.getInstalledApplications`.

> How does the Android System determinate the Space for the
>   Applications? I expected to found a vertical Layout like this...

You can find statusbar related things in this folder : src/com/android/systemui/statusbar
and navigationbar is defined in  ./src/com/android/systemui/statusbar/phone/NavigationBarView.java